# Need help to understand the wiring for these light switches

Tags: electrical

So I have a three gang utility box with three light switches, the box is located on the main floor.  Below are the pictures.

In the first picture the supply cable enters the box via #6

#4 and #5 feeding two power plugs

#1,#2,#3 are the cable runs that are controlled by the three switches in the second picture.

Still referring to the first picture: the cable run #1  can be controlled either by the switch #1 (middle switch in the second picture) or by a switch in the basement. This is for the lights installed on the stairs that lead to the basement.

The other two cables(#2,#3) control lights in the area where the box is located

Here are my questions:
1)shouldn't these three switches have a ground wire ????
2)now for the wiring please refer to the third picture

here is my understanding please correct me if I am wrong

- #1,#2,#3 are all loads, the switch is
  controlling a 4 wire cable and both switches (the downstairs one and
  the one in the picture can close the circuit)
- #10 is the load that comes from the supply circuit and then it feeds all three switches using these links: #6-#8,##7-#3
- #7 or #8 and #9 are connected (circuit closed) when the switch to the right is closed so this is OK

  2a)I do not understand, why #5 is white, what is its role, shouldn't it be black?

  2b)I do not understand why #4 is there and why it is needed ? This is controlling a large chandelier with lots of bulbs

What strikes me first is the fact that there is no ground on any of the light switches.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If a metal box(looks like it) then the screws holding the switches to the box act as ground path(separate ground wire not required).  Most switches using a black and white wire cable can use the white wire as hot(black), not neutral to save wire.  The white wire should have black tape/paint on it at both ends, saying it is hot.

Comment: Those switches seem to be using back stabs.  Most of the ones who know do not like them(tend to cause problems) and prefer to use the screws.

Comment: don't see why I would have 4&5 in the third picture (both hot as you say) going back into the same cable ...that means at the other end you have two hots...what is the purpose of that ?

Comment: Probably a switch loop.  Power is at the light, but goes to switch, then to black light wire on the other.  White connected to power at light, then to switch and black is switch hot back to light.  Three and four way switches can get confusing.

Comment: Notes to your question should be added with an [edit] to your question, not an answer.  This is not a discussion forum, they have discussion forums for electrical but the signal/noise ratio is *terrible*.  Perhaps that is why you are here instead lol.   Well, the Q/A format is *how*  we keep the S/N high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the second circuit is also controlled by two switches and switch 1 and  switch two are wired the same way, just the cable colors are a little bit different
They are three way switches required by that setup ...
As @crip659 mentioned in the comments wire #5 in the second picture could be a load as well